# SQL server 2012: Where are the "ALL SERVER" triggers scripts stored

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Where would a trigger be stored if I created it to trigger on "ALL SERVER".

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_LogonAttempt ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'dbo'
```

I would like to be able to find and modify it again if I close it down. I know where triggers are normally saved in the object explorer under table.
Thank you.

Comment: In SSMS: [Your Server Instance] -> Server Objects -> Triggers

Comment: Thats's great. Cheers for that. Was hard enough to find.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get this from the catalog view in the `master` database:

```
USE master;
GO

SELECT name, OBJECT_DEFINITION ([object_id]) 
FROM sys.server_triggers
-- WHERE name = N'trg_LogonAttempt'
;
```

You can also script it through the UI, as @Michael pointed out - server-level triggers are stored under Instance > Server Objects > Triggers:

> [image]

Comment: That is more convenient. A better approach.

Comment: The extra options. I do not know what they do. Do they make it more convenient to carry out some functionalities that some scripting?

Comment: @EP what extra options?

Comment: in the screenshot. the "script server trigger as" -> "drop and create to" options. Do they make it easier to create triggers for a server or is that a totally different question altogether for another post?

Comment: Well I chose that option because ALTER is greyed out. Typically you would rather do an ALTER on most user objects in your regular databases, so that you don't lose things like dependencies and permissions. On server-level triggers, though, there is much less worry about that. IMHO.