# How to get server trigger definition in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I found many ways to get the Trigger definition one of the best way for me is `OBJECT_DEFINITION`.
Unfortunately  it doesn't work for triggers from `master.sys.server_triggers`;

How I can get the definition of server trigger?

Comment: Off topic and duplicate - [dba - get definition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214503/how-to-get-the-definition-of-a-database-trigger)

Comment: @SMor you are wrong, My question about system triggers, your question about other tables and I wrote about it. Do you try to understand my question? Why did you decide that this is duplicate ?

Comment: Read the link - the question OP asked at the bottom of the post is literally "How then, do I get the database triggers definition?" Which was intended to refer "DDL trigger" - and Marcello's suggestion does that.

Comment: I asked about SERVER trigger ON DATABASE CREATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: here [SQL server 2012: Where are the "ALL SERVER" triggers scripts stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404097/sql-server-2012-where-are-the-all-server-triggers-scripts-stored)

I **must** use master db

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT 
sys.triggers.name, 
sys.sql_modules.definition
FROM sys.triggers
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules 
    ON OBJECT_ID(sys.triggers.name) = sys.sql_modules.object_id
WHERE type = 'TR';
```

Comment: Thank you but I asked about triggers from system_triggers

Comment: Is there a point to using `OBJECT_ID(sys.triggers.name)`, when there's also `sys.object_id`, which seems to produce the same value? I.e. is there any edge case, this is handling?